# how to determine whether a attribute is continuous in C 4.5 decision tree

Tags: python, attributes, continuous

How do I determine whether a attribute is continuous in [C4.5 decision tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm) implementation?

Comment: This is pretty general, in the algorithm _you_ input the attributes, why wouldn't you know if an attribute is continuous or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You** determine if any attribute is continous or not.

**You** feed the data to the DT.

Attributes are the properties of the **data** not the decision tree.